# django app that runs constantly in the backend

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

hey guys, im trying to run a script in the backend of my django project, i have used django signals to call my script and run it when foo class is saved, and in the foo class theres a variable that can be true or false,  if its true it calls an infinte loop that runs a function every x seconds, but since this is an infinite loop, its keeping the django HTTPRequest active, so the page never finishes loading, is there a way to bipass this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run tasks asynchronously have a look at [django-celery](https://github.com/ask/django-celery)!

EDIT: of course you can also set up a good old cron job on your system....